# Performing add/delete/count operations on a list

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded, bitwise

> **Problem Statement ([HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/countercode/challenges/subset))**
>
> You have a list of integers, initially the list is empty.
>
> You have to process Q operations of three kinds:
>
> - add s: Add integer s to your list, note that an integer can exist more
>     than one time in the list
> - del s: Delete one copy of integer s from the list, it's guaranteed
>     that at least one copy of s will exist in the list.
> - cnt s: Count how many integers a are there in the list such that a AND
>     s = a, where AND is bitwise AND operator
>
> **Input Format**
>
> First line contains an integer Q.  Each of the following Q lines
>   contains an operation type string T and an integer s.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - \$1 \le Q \le 200000\$
> - \$0 \le s \lt 2^{16}\$
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each **cnt s** operation, output the answer in a new line.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 7 
> add 11 
> cnt 15 
> add 4 
> add 0 
> cnt 6 
> del 4 
> cnt 15
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 1 
> 2 
> 2
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> For first line, we have 15 AND 11 = 11 so the answer is 1
>
> For second line, 6 AND 0 = 0 and 6 AND 4 = 4 so the answer is 2
>
> For third line, 4 has been deleted and we have 15 AND 11 = 11 and 15
>   AND 0 = 0 so the answer is 2

My working code:

```
operations = int(raw_input())
current = 1
lst = []
while current <= operations:
    count = 0
    input_ = raw_input().split()
    operation = input_[0]
    num = int(input_[1])
    if operation == 'add':
        lst.append(num)
    elif operation == 'cnt':
        for number in lst:
            if number & num == number:
                count += 1
        print(count)
    elif operation == 'del':
        lst.remove(num)
    current += 1
```

Comment: We are allowed to use `list.count` but it doesn't serve a purpose as we have to count only those numbers which satisfy the given condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't exploit the nature of the question.

> **Constraints**
>
> - \$1 \le Q \le 200000\$
> - \$0 \le s \lt 2 ^ {16}\$

Why are these important? It's so you can achieve greater performance, for a price in memory.

You know that there is \$2 ^ {16}\$ possible numerical inputs,
and there is a maximum of 200000 inputs.

If the last input is count, and all the rest are add,
you will be recounting numbers a lot. Leading to a dramatic performance loss.

First you would want to prevent recounting if possible.
One way to do this is to make a dictionary to count the occurrences of numbers.
However due to constant type changes you can just use a list instead.

```
lst = [0] * (2 ** 16)
```

This takes more time than using `lst = []`, but it will pay off.

---

If we look at the performance of your 3 functions.
I use the information from Python's [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list) page.

### Add

```
lst.append(num)
```

This is average case \$O(1)\$, worst case \$O(n)\$, (not amortized worst case).

`lst` is internally stored as an array,
and so if you grow past the bounds all the data must move.

And so I will say this is \$O(n)\$.

### Del

```
lst.remove(num)
```

This is average case \$O(n)\$, worst case \$O(n)\$.

And so this is \$O(n)\$.

### cnt

```
for number in lst:
    if number & num == number:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

And again this is \$O(n)\$.

### Overall

You can have 200000 calls to functions that are \$O(n)\$.
If you ask me that's not good on performance.

---

You can easly make `add` and `del` \$O(1)\$.

If you use `lst = [0] * (2 ** 16)`.

```
if operation == 'add':
    lst[num] += 1
elif operation == 'del':
    lst[num] -= 1
```

It's like using a default-dictionary where the index is only numbers.
However this currently will have the drawback of `cnt` always being \$O(2 ^ {16})\$.

If you wish to fix that you can use a set, to store the numbers, so it is \$O(n)\$.

Here is a solution that passes a few more of the tests. It does not pass them all.

```
operations = int(raw_input())
nums = set()
storage = [0] * (2 ** 16)

for _ in xrange(operations): 
    input_ = raw_input().split()
    operation = input_[0]
    num = int(input_[1])

    if operation == 'add':
        nums |= {num}
        storage[num] += 1
    elif operation == 'cnt':
        print(sum(
            storage[number]
            for number in nums
            if (number & num) == number
        ))
    elif operation == 'del':
        storage[num] -= 1
```

This uses a similar solution as yours, my `lst` is `nums`.
However, I aimed at obtaining \$O(1)\$ in both `add` and `del`.

---

I can't complete the problem.
The way Python programmers that solved this use `[0] * (2 ** 16)` and binary logic I don't know. Which make all the functions \$O(256)\$.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of looping structure:

```
loop_counter = start_value
while loop_count < end_value:
    # Several lines of other code
    loop_counter += 1
```

is discouraged in most languages, because it spreads details about what is really one logical operation across your code. The preferred Python for this is:

```
for loop_counter in range(start_value, end_value):
    # Other code
```

Note that `end_value` is not included in the range, and you may need to choose it with that in mind.

You initialise a variable called `count` at the top of your loop, but it's only used in one of the branches of the `if` statement. For the same reason as above, it should go near where it's used:

```
elif operation == 'cnt':
    count = 0
    # Your current loop
```

You can check that this list comprehension will give you all the True/False results of that `if` in that loop:

```
[(number & num) == number for number in lst]
```

Once you're happy with that, you can count how many are True just by adding them up (try these: `True + True`, `True + True + True + False`). That means that this (dropping the `[]` to make it a generator expression because we don't need it as a list to do this):

```
count = sum((number & num) == number for number in lst)
```

will give you the same answer as your `for` loop. You can almost read it as a sentence: "to get count, add up which numbers in `lst` have this interesting property".

Comment: Doesn't get improved much. I am still getting timeout.

Comment: @DarthShadow are you able to provide a link to the challenge?

Comment: [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/countercode/challenges/subset)

Comment: This doesn't improve performance a lot, but it has some valid points about syntax and idiomatic python.

Answer (score 0):

You are requested to implement a data structure which can implement the three commands: `add`, `cnt`, `del`. What is the minimal information you have to hold? To respond to a `cnt` command it is enough to store 216 possible answers, corresponding to 216 possible values of `s`. That is enough. When you `add` a number `a`, just add 1 to the count of all `s` such that `a&s == a`. To `del` a number just decrement the counter. So here is the core of a possible (not tested) implementation:

```
class CountMachine(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.count = [0] * 216

   def cnt(self, s):
      return self.count[s]

   def add(self, a, step=1):
      for s in range(len(self.count)):
          if (a & s) == a:
             self.count[s] += step

   def del(self, a):
      self.add(a, step=-1)
```

Comment: Note that it is 2^16, not 216. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: well, this changes things a lot!